# public boolean equals(Object other)

Tags: java

This is for a Fraction program. I have private ints num and den, Fraction, and FractionInterface - the standard homework problem. I have done pretty much everything and now have been stuck for a few hours on the equals method. Since other is an Object, I can't equate it to Fraction. Here's what I have:

```java
public boolean equals(Object other){        
     if (other == this){
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
}
```

This compiles but it gives incorrect results:

```
1/2 eq 1/2 = true
1/2 eq 1/2 = true
1/2 eq 1/2 = false
1/2 eq 1/2 = false
```

If I try other == Fraction, it doesn't compile. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you know what classes come in as `other`?  Also, +1 for marking this homework and a well posed question!

Comment: Be aware that most of the answers so far will fail if `other` implements `FractionInterface` but is not of class `Fraction`. You should be clear in your mind whether you want a solution that works only when `other` is an instance of `Fraction`, or one that works when `other` is an instance of `Fraction` or one of its subclasses, or one that works for any object that implements `FractionInterface`. You need different code for each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

First, cast the `other` object

```
Fraction otherFraction = (Fraction) other;
```

Then, determine the condition that the two fractions are equivalent.
This will include some logic involving the comparing of numerator and denominators (expect to use `getNum()` and `getDen()` for the `otherFraction`.

Comment: Thanks! I had already tried casting the 'other' object just like you said, but instead of getting the numerator and denominator from it, I was trying to directly compare it to the other fraction. Yet another simple mistake I was making. It works now, using the Get methods and cross multiplication. Thanks again!!

Comment: Good call James. I remember in my AP Java class we were not expected to do anything about the fact that this statement can blow up. Without having to introduce reflection, I might suggest to beginners to try wrapping stuff in try-catch statements.

Comment: I do have try-catch statements for exceptions.

Comment: `equals()` may get called elsewhere, where you don't have try-catch. It's a good practice to check if it is fine to cast first before casting.

Comment: Use `instanceof` for other before casting using fraction.

Answer (score 2):

You can test if `other` is an instance of `FractionInterface` and use a cast:

```
public boolean equals(Object other){        
     if (other == this){
         return true;
     } else if (other instanceof FractionInterface) {
         FractionInterface fOther = (FractionInterface) other;
         // compare numerator and denominator...
     } else {
         return false;
     }
}
```

Note that `instanceof` will be `false` if `other == null`, so there's no need for a separate null check.

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether the argument is an instance of your class and return `false` if it isn't and cast it to your class and compare according to your needs if it is. It's common to write `equals()` method like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Fraction)) {
        return false;
    }
    Fraction that = (Fraction) obj;
    ... // Your algorithm to compare two fractions: this and that.
}
```

You should make sure that your algorithm for comparing two fractions meets all the requirements described in `equals()` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 0):

You need to test if the object has the Fraction class, and if so, cast it to a Fraction:

```
if (other.getClass() != Fraction.class) {
    return false;
}
Fraction otherFraction = (Fraction) other;
// compare the fields of this and otherFraction
```

Before doing this, make sure to also test for null.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use `instanceof`?

Comment: Because if Fraction is extended and the subclass overrides equals, using instanceof would break the contract of equals: `fraction.equals(subFraction)` would be true, whereas `subFraction.equals(fraction)` would be false.

Comment: It's very difficult to implement equals correctly with `instanceof` if Fraction has subclasses, so getClass is a popular alternative.

Comment: @JBNizet if extending the class breaks equals than you should not be using inheritance, this is where composition comes into play.

Comment: Extending the class doesn't break equals if it's properly implemented, by not using instanceof. If using instanceof, then equals should be final.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing that the two objects references refer to the same object.

You will need to check that the `other` is of type `Fraction` and then type cast it to a `Fraction`. You are then about to compare the two parts of the `Fraction`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close, but you're missing a few key concepts.  This is because your as is won't work in all situations.  Try this for example using your existing code...

```
Fraction a = // this is however you're making a fraction object...
Fraction b = // do EXACT same thing here that you did for a

// And then, this will illustrate what is wrong with your program...
if(a.equals(b)) {
  System.out.println("This won't print");
} else {
  System.out.println("This will print because your method just checks for reference");
}
```

So here are the basics you need to understand:

1. Difference between `==` and `equals`
2. Comparing type as opposed to reference or value
3. Avoiding casting by putting your "equals" method in the proper place

First off...

```
public boolean equals(Object other){        
     if (other == this){
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
}
```

You're missing the point of the "equals" method in Java.  `==` is used to compare references while `this.equals(foo)` is used to put the logic for comparing objects in a localized place.

The other concept you're missing is how instanceof should be used.  When you ask this...

> If I try other == Fraction, it doesn't compile.

This is because you're looking to compare the type of the object.  To do this, you would simply do...

```
if(other instanceOf Fraction) {
  // do stuff...
}
```

All of that being said, there is one last concept, which is putting the equals definition in the proper place.  You need to put it inside your Fraction class and define it like this...

```
public boolean equals(Fraction other) {
  // do something like this (you will have to define toDouble)
  if(this == other || this.toDouble() == other.toDouble()) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

This will override the default...

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {/* ... */}
```

And it will make it EXTREMELY convenient.  Here is some sample code of how...

```
Fraction fractionA = new Fraction("2/4");
Fraction fractionB = new Fraction("1/2");
Fraction fractionC = new Fraction("1/3");
Object trollObject = new Object();

// And then call random equals objects...
if(fractionA.equals(fractionB)) {
  // should be true...
}

if(fractionB.equals(fractionA)) {
  // should be true...
}

// This avoids having to do any casting because
// since you've only defined a Fraction.equals(Fraction) method
// it should instead default to the Object.equals method
if(trollObject.equals(fractionB)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quite standard pattern:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == this) return true;
    if (other == null) return false;
    if (other.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;

    Fraction o = (Fraction) other;
    // now you compare their num, den, and possibly sign
}
```

People may argue if we should use `getClass()` or `instanceof`. It matters only if `Fraction` is extended, and it depends on what you want if it is extended. Just keep in mind a contract of `equals()` is `a.equals(b)` should get the same result as `b.equals(a)` if neither one is `null`, and a subclass may have a different `equals()` that potentially breaks the contract.

Comment: This also won't work if `other` is not a `Fraction` at all but some other object implementing `FractionInterface`.

Comment: Right. It really depends on what you want if `other` is not a `Fraction` but implements `FractionInterface`. It's a gray area. When in doubt, I prefer returning `false`. If `other` has an extra `sign` field and we have no access to it, we should simply return `false`

Answer (score -1):

== operator compares hash codes of objects. That is reason why your method is not ok, you should write it like this :

```
public boolean equals(Object other){        
     if (other instanceof Fraction){
         return ((Fraction)other).getNum == this.num && ((Fraction)other).getDen == this.den;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong!! == compares what is stored on the stack. For primitives this is the acctual value and for objects it is the reference to the heap there the object is stored. The hashcode should be equal for two objects becouse there will be problems then using hashmaps

Comment: Yes you are right my bad. It was late night when i was typing answer :)

Answer (score -1):

I hope that it will helpful to you .try this code.

```
import java.io.*;

class Cast

{

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException

{

BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

byte a=20;

short s=31468;

int i=12345678;

char c=’c';

float f=3.56f;

//Widening or promotion [java question bank][1]

System.out.println(“a=(short)  “+(short) a);

System.out.println(“a=(int)  “+(int) a);

System.out.println(“a=(long)  “+(long)a);

System.out.println(“a=(float)  “+(float)a);

System.out.println();

System.out.println();

System.out.println(“s=(int) “+(int)s);

System.out.println(“s=(long)  “+(long)s);

System.out.println(“s=(float)  “+(float)s);

System.out.println();

System.out.println();

System.out.println(“i=(long)  “+(long)i);

System.out.println(“i=(float)  “+(float)i);

System.out.println(“i=(double)  “+(double)i);


//Narrowing using [java question bank][2]

System.out.println(“f=(byte)  “+(byte)f);

System.out.println(“f=(short)  “+(short)f);

System.out.println(“f=(char)  “+(char)f);

System.out.println(“f=(long)  “+(long)f);

System.out.println();

System.out.println();

System.out.println(“i=(byte)  “+(byte)i);

System.out.println(“i=(short)  “+(short)i);

System.out.println();

System.out.println();

System.out.println(“s=(byte)  “+(byte)s);


}

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will help the OP. Care to elaborate?